# Which ASIC manufacturer (if any) made ASICs for XMR in the past?

Tags: mining, asic-mining

I checked out the medium post by MoneroCrusher over at [medium.com](https://medium.com/@MoneroCrusher/analysis-more-than-85-of-the-current-monero-hashrate-is-asics-and-each-machine-is-doing-128-kh-s-f39e3dca7d78) which indicates that at one point in time, ASICs were most likely operating on the monero network.
Has anyone figured out who was behind it?

Answer (score 3):

There may have been others, but at least [Baikalminer](https://twitter.com/baikalminer/status/983278127504769026)<sup>[[archive]](https://archive.is/NifM8)</sup> and [Bitmain](https://twitter.com/BITMAINtech/status/974180147166261248)<sup>[[archive]](https://archive.is/TydRi)</sup> launched Monero ASIC miners in 2018.

It's worth noting Bitmain allowed people to buy the ASICs, but didn't actually ship them until after the Monero hardfork - meaning only Bitmain themselves were able to mine XMR on their own ASICs, and knowingly scammed their customers thereafter.

Comment: Ha.  Was listening to Epicenter Bitcoin Episode 314 with Nishant Sharma from Bitmain who really sounded like he was lying through his teeth the whole time, but I wasn't sure.